# No straighforward way to access the text of deleted answer with a single revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, user-interface

When I view [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24197129) (link won't work for users with less than 10k rep), it shows this text instead of the actual text of the answer:*

> This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.

But there is no link to get to the revision history, presumably because the answer only has one revision.

I've figured out two ways to get to the text of the answer, but both of them are pretty unintuitive:

1. Click the “edit” link. This works just like for normal posts and shows the code of the answer along with a rendered preview.
2. Find out the ID of the answer from the URL of one of the links (“share”, “edit”, …), then figure out the URL pattern for revision history of posts and combine the two. In this case, the result is https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24197129/revisions. This might be a somewhat acceptable approach on SO (we're all programmers here), but certainly not on other SE sites.

I can think of two ways of fixing this:

1. Show the revision history link for such answers, even if they have just a single revision.
2. Just change the wording of the message to point users to the “edit” link instead (or in addition to) the revision history.

---

* This particular answer should have been deleted as “not a real answer”, it's not actually spam or offensive. But that's not the point here.

Comment: Fix 3. Make "revision history" in the text a link to the post's revision history.

Comment: @Anthony Yeah, that's even better.