# Can owner of post view its revisions after it's deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, revision-history

Here's scenario:

I first create a post on stackoverflow, and then do some edit on the post. Then I delete the post.

Will I able to see its revision now?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260446/no-straighforward-way-to-access-the-text-of-deleted-answer-with-a-single-revisio and also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287032/let-me-see-the-source-of-my-own-answers-that-have-been-deleted-please slightly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296610/can-the-5-minute-grace-period-cause-data-loss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.

> Edits will be rolled into the previous revision if the previous revision was created by the same author and *none* of the following conditions are present:
>
> - The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor.
> - An answer has been added to the post since the previous revision
> - The previous revision was a rollback
> - The new revision is a rollback

[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/158100)

When a post is deleted the owner and any moderator or user with a reputation of 10K or more can see the deleted posts, including their revisions.

Do note that once a revision is saved only employees can edit or remove the revisions as explained in [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57925/can-moderators-high-rep-users-delete-revisions-from-the-revision-history)

Comment: Only for 60 days, correct? "we're showing a link (visible only to profile owners and moderators) on the Questions and Answers tabs that'll list the given user's deleted questions or answers, currently limited to those posted in the past 60 days." from [How recent are 'Deleted recent answers'?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289691)

Comment: @DavidPostill you can always look at your own deleted posts. After 60 days you have a hard-time finding them...

Comment: I know. I don't keep links to all my old deleted answers. I suppose a SEDE query could be used ...

Comment: @DavidPostill SEDE doesn't have the owneruserid filled for PostsWithDeleted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

Comment: Hmm. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/263142/find-deleted-answers-by-user finds some of my deleted answers, but not all. Anyway it doesn't really matter. My original comment was just an observation about the 60 days.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone able to see any post can always see the revision history of that post.

You're able to see all of your own posts, even if they're deleted.

Therefore, you can see the revision history of all of your deleted posts.

Comment: Only for 60 days, correct? "we're showing a link (visible only to profile owners and moderators) on the Questions and Answers tabs that'll list the given user's deleted questions or answers, currently limited to those posted in the past 60 days." from [How recent are 'Deleted recent answers'?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289691)

Comment: @DavidPostill You're only given the link for 60 days; you can view the post until the end of time, if you remember or saved the link to the question.